# Chrome inline-block not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I am trying to create a basic HTML page layout. The code is working fine in latest version of the firefox, but not in chrome(v31).
The Problem: Chrome inserts a line break after the second div. Is this a chrome bug or my code is wrong? If it is a chrome bug then what is the workaround or fix?

```
<div class="div-1"></div><div class="div-2"></div><div class="div-3">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="uid">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

            <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

stylesheet

```
@import url("reset.css");
.div-1 {
background-color: green;
height:30px;
width: inherit;
}

.div-2 {
background-color: red;
height: 275px;
width: 752px;
display: inline-block;
}

.div-3 {
background-color: blue;
height: auto;
width: 255px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkya4649/gxQKt/)

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/R6yvq/. Using Chrome: 33.0.  Note: I've changed the width of  div-2 to fit the jsfiddle window.

Comment: I see no differences between Chrome/FF here..

Comment: Hmm. I think the problem only pops up specifically in my version of chrome. I am a beginner and just wanted to make sure that I wasn't the culprit here. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float: right;` on `.div-3` and it gives a 'context' to your div and the `display:inline-block;` is useless.

The `width: inherit;` on `.div-1` is also useless because a block will always take all the width available from his closest parent